# Reference request for certain PDE appearing in a probability application

Tags: probability, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, stochastic-processes

In working on a stochastic processes application, I derived a PDE for the joint transform of some process. It takes the form $$\frac{\partial \zeta(t,z,s)}{\partial t}-(\beta s+1)\frac{\partial\zeta(t,z,s)}{\partial s}=\frac{z}{s}\left(\zeta(t,z,0)-\zeta(t,z,s)\right),$$ where we have boundary conditions $\zeta(0,z,s)=e^{-s}$, $\zeta(t,0,s)=0$ and $\zeta(t,1,0)=1$. Here $\beta>0$ is just some scalar. If convenient, I'm fine with setting it to unity.

I don't have much experience with PDE, and I'm a bit stuck in this problem because I either want to solve this PDE or I'd like to calculate expressions like $\frac{\partial \zeta(t,z,s)}{\partial z}$ evaluated in $(t,1,0)$ for arbitrary $t>0$. In this context, it may be helpful to use the expression $\zeta(t,z,s)=\mathbb Ez^{N(t)}e^{-s\Lambda(t)}$ from my probability application. Rewriting the PDE and using this expression gives us ODEs for moments of $N(t),\Lambda(t)$, but only expressed in higher moments, making a recursive solution inpossible. Therefore I'm looking for something different.

I was hoping this PDE belongs to some well-known class, or for some analytical method to solve this PDE; I'm looking for some reference. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: There are no derivatives wrt $z$ in your equation, so $z$ appears only as a *parameter*. You have a PDE for $\zeta(t,s)$. Were it not for the term $\zeta(t,0)$ on the RHS, the solution would follow directly using the method of characteristics. One way to proceed is to differentiate the whole expression wrt $s$. This eliminates the troublesome term on the RHS and leaves a second order linear PDE

Comment: What kind of stochastic process was this derived from? Some sort of jump process? You may be out of luck for analytic solutions and might have use numerical methods. Or you can at least solve it numerically to study its behavior and think of possible analytic approximations.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Indeed, this was derived from a jump process, one where the rate collapses by a stochastic factor at each jump.

Comment: @Sal Differentiating w.r.t. $s$ does not seem to help to get rid of $\zeta(t,z,0)$, because we have the factor $\frac zs$

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov Multiply by $s$ first ;)

Comment: I didn't think about that, thanks!

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov No problem. If you don't multiply bu $s$ first, you can still eliminate the offending term if you use the original equation to eliminate it. Also: there may be some scaling argument that fixes the dependence of $\zeta$ on $z$, but I'm unsure at the moment

Comment: How about spherical coordinates ?

Comment: Any luck following Sal’s suggestion to multiply by $s$ and then differentiate in $s$? Then you might apply the Fourier transform to the resulting PDE and obtain an ODE

Comment: @NapD.Lover Thank you for your suggestion. I tried this, treating $z$ as a parameter. However, because of terms like $s\frac{\partial u_z(t,s)}{\partial s}$ it seems that by taking the Fourier transform we get a PDE that seems to be of similar (if not higher) difficulty, if I'm not mistaking...

Comment: In the expression $\zeta(s,z,t)=\mathbb{E}z^Ne^{-s\Lambda}$ what is $\mathbb{E}$? An expectation value? If so, wrt what? Because you have $s,z,t$ on both LHS and RHS

Comment: Its wrt to $N(t)$ and $\Lambda(t)$, which are the counts and a rate function of some stochastic process. Thank you for your answer, I'll award you the bounty.

Comment: @VáclavMordvinov no problem!

Answer (score 4):

I'll write $f(t,s)$ rather than $\zeta$, and set $\beta=1$. The equation is

$$\tag{1}
s\partial_tf(t,s)-s(s+1)\partial_s f(t,s)=zf(t,0)-zf(t,s)
$$

This is a non-local differential equation due to the first term on the RHS. It can be recast as an integro-differential equation by writing the RHS as $\int\limits_0^s ds' \frac{\partial f}{\partial s'}$. We will find a class of formal solutions to (1) as integrals. Take a partial Fourier transform in $t$ to get

$$\tag{2}
-i\omega s F(\omega,s)-s(s+1)\partial_s F(\omega,s)=z F(\omega,0)-zF(\omega,s)
$$

Where $F(\omega,s)=\int dt \ f(t,s)e^{i\omega t}$. If we differentiate (2) wrt $s$ we eliminate the non-local term and are left with a linear ODE for $F(s)$ (temporarily suppressing the $\omega$ dependence)

$$\tag{3}
s(s+1)F''+(2s+1+i\omega s-z)F'+i\omega F=0
$$

Using a CAS, we find the general solution to (3) is

$$\tag{4}
(1+s)^{z+i\omega}F(s)=A(\omega)s^z+B(\omega)(-s)^z \beta(-s,-z,i\omega+z)
$$

Where $\beta$ is the [incomplete beta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html). $A(\omega)$ and $B(\omega)$ are the integration 'constants'. Substituting (4) into (2) we find that (4) satisfies (2) for *any* $A$ and $B$. Taking the inverse Fourier transform of the first term in (4) yields

$$\tag{5}
f_A(t,s)=\left(\frac{s}{s+1}\right)^z\int\frac{d \omega}{2\pi} \ A(\omega) \exp\left[-i \omega(t+\ln(1+s)) \right]
$$

If the initial condition is given as $f(0,s)=\psi(s)$, then we can; in principle, determine $A$. Let $\eta=\ln(1+s)$, so that at $t=0$ we have from (5)

$$\tag{6}
\frac{1}{(1-e^{-\eta})^z}\psi(e^\eta-1)=\int\frac{d\omega}{2\pi} \ e^{-i\omega \eta} A(\omega)
$$

So that $A(\omega)$ is determined by the initial condition as a Fourier transform in $\eta$.

$$\tag{7}
A(\omega)=\int d\eta \  \frac{e^{i\omega \eta}\psi(e^\eta-1)}{(1-e^{-\eta})^z}
$$

Then (5) reads

$$\tag{8}
f_A(t,s)= \int\frac{d \omega}{2\pi}\int d\eta' \ \left[\frac{1-e^{-\eta}}{1-e^{-\eta'}}\right]^z e^{-i \omega(t+\eta-\eta') } \psi(e^{\eta'}-1) 
$$

The RHS is implicitly a function of $s$ since $\eta=\eta(s)$. All integrals are $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty$. Actually performing the integrals analytically seems unfeasible, but (8) already tells you about the full $z$ dependence of $f$. You may differentiate (8) wrt $z$ to find things like $\frac{d}{dz}f|_{z=1}$.

Notes:

1. You may wonder about taking a partial Fourier transform wrt $s$ instead of $t$. In this case (using the usual rules of Fourier transforms), we find a linear PDE with delta source term

$$\tag{9}
k\partial_{kk}G+(ik+2)\partial_k G + \partial_{kt}G +(1+z)G=2\pi i z  \delta(k)
$$

Where $G=G(t,k)$ is the Fourier transform of $f(t,s)$. (9) says that solutions to (1) are the Fourier transforms of the Green's functions of the linear operator

$$\tag{10}
\hat{L}=k\partial_{kk} +(ik+2)\partial_k + \partial_{kt} +(1+z)
$$

Which is presumably, after a co-ordinate change, equal to the Helmholtz operator. (9) may be useful for generating the solutions numerically.

2. Taking a full Fourier transform yields a linear ODE

$$\tag{11}
k F'' +(ik-i\omega+2)F'+i(z+1)F=2\pi i z \delta(k)
$$

Where $F'=\partial_k F$. The solutions of (11) are

$$\tag{12}
e^{ik}k^{1-i\omega}F(\omega,k)=A(\omega)U(-z,i\omega,ik)+B(\omega)L(z,i\omega-1,ik)
$$

Where $U$ is a [confluent hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function) function and $L$ is a [generalized Laguerre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials#Generalized_Laguerre_polynomials).

3. If the nonlocal term were absent, the solution would follow directly from the [method of characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics). The solution in that case is

$$\tag{13}
f(t,s)=z^{1+(1-e^{-t})/s}\psi(e^t(s+1)-1)
$$